# Asterisk(wild card match) and url-pattern

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'd like to have an "explicit" servlet for a particular URL and a default(sort of a catch-all) servlet to handle all other URLs. So I created the web.xml file like this :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>My myindex.html servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>in.shakir.web.MyIndexServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My myindex.html servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myindex.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>My all others servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>in.shakir.web.MyHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>My all others servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

However it is not working(I get 404 error even for /myindex.html)
I am using Tomcat 7.

But if I remove second (default or catch-all) part from my web.xml, then myindex.html works fine. So whats wrong with my url-pattern ? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

see [this](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html) for more information.

Comment: Chandra, I just read that page and it seems that using <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> and <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
will have the same effect. Right ?

Comment: @user1089770 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> will act as default url pattern. I mean if no url is matched, then this servlet will be called. But I don't think 2nd case is exist in servlet. Wll i am not sure about 2nd case.